# Take any number N greater than 2P, will there be always be a number that isn't a multiple of 2,3...P between N and N+2P

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I was working on the Bertrand's postulate(which states that there's always a prime between any integer n and 2n), and I wonder if it won't only work for 1,2,3...2P for set of primes (2,3,5...P), but also for integers N, N+1, N+2....N+2P for set of primes (2,3,5...P). I checked so far for numbers bigger than 2P, say N. And I checked for numbers between N and N+2P, and I always found a number relatvely prime to 2,3,...P.  For example say, (2,3,5,7), let N be 20, between 20 and 34, there are 3 numbers, 23, 29, and 31 that are relatively primes to (2,3,5,7). Now will this be true for numbers between N and N+2P using primes (2,3,5...P)?

Comment: This seems like a "shifted" form of Bertrand's Postulate, and almost certainly true but requiring much the same tools to prove it.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a shifted form of the postulate, and will require probably the same tools, or more, but can we actually prove it?

Comment: Apart from this, it's actually a weaker form of that. In the sense that, we are to find numbers that are not multiples of set (2,3,5...P). So the number can be a prime or a relative prime compared to the set (2,3,5...P). So between 48 and 48+2(5): between 48-58 for set (2,3,5), we have 49 which is not a multiple of 2,3, it exists between N and N+2P and it's not even a prime number. So it's a shift of the Bertrand postulate, but we are not just looking for primes, but also relative primes, hence weaker. @Joffan

Comment: I don't really think it's weaker, since Bertrand's Postulate just has N=0 with a special dispensation to ignore 0 and 1. Then the first half of the range is a washout and we're only going to find new divisors in the second half. You can achieve a similar effect at N=P# (except of course P#+1 gives a new prime divisor immediately).